# When is it better to utilize machine learning over heuristics?

Tags: machine-learning, mlops, production-systems

I learned that 87% of machine learning projects fail due to these five pitfalls:

1. the scope of the project is too big;
2. the project’s scope increased in size as the project progressed—e.g., scope creep;
3. the model couldn’t be explained, hence there was lack of trust in the solution;
4. the model was too complex; and
5. the project solved the wrong problem.

And I learned that rules and heuristic approaches may be a better choice than machine learning, since the development of machine learning takes more time(and more costly) and its explanation is also harder.

Then I wonder when we should just use rules and heuristics and when we should bravely take the machine learning approach?

References:

1. [Why Ai/Data Science Projects Fail](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1636390382)

Answer (score 0):

> Machine learning is an approach to (1) learn (2) complex patterns from (3) existing data and use these patterns to make (4) predictions on (5) unseen data.

Then there are 9 use cases here:

1. Learn: the system has the capacity to learn
2. Complex patterns: there are patterns to learn, and they are complex ML
3. Existing data: data is available, or it’s possible to collect data
4. Predictions: it’s a predictive problem
5. Unseen data: Unseen data shares patterns with the training data
6. It’s repetitive
7. The cost of wrong predictions is cheap
8. It’s at scale
9. The patterns are constantly changing

> However, even if ML can’t solve your problem, it might be possible to break your problem into smaller components, and use ML to solve some of them.

References:

1. [Designing Machine Learning Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1098107969)